# Read a web page with all images in Base64-Embedded format

Tags: c#, html, web

In my scenario I want to download the HTML of a page (any page on the Internet) programaticaly but also I want all of the images in the HTML to be in **base64 embedded format** (not referenced)

In other words, instead of :

```
<img src='/images/delete.gif' />
```

I want the downloaded html to look like this:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl..." />
```

This way I don't need to go through the process of storing all images in directories, etc, etc.

Does any of you have any idea how this can be done? Or any plugin to do this efficiently?

Comment: Images in a base-64 string are larger in size, and make the HTML source unreadable. Why would you turn all external sources in base-64 strings?

Comment: how is this not a real question!!

Comment: I'm OK with the size, because all that size is going to be requested from the net in multiple requests anyway.

Comment: That's the exactly my case. The images are very small so I don't care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you'd need to:

- Download the original HTML
- Find each `img` element in the HTML (for instance using the [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)) and for each one:

  - If it's already using a data URL, ignore it
  - Otherwise:
  - Download the image
  - Encoded it in Base64 using `Convert.ToBase64String`
  - Replace the original `img` tag with one using the base64 version (either in the original string, or via a DOM representation)
- Save the final HTML to disk

Is any of these steps causing you a particular problem? You could potentially make it quicker by downloading the images in parallel, but I'd get a serial version working first.

Comment: I was curious to see if there is a magical way of doing this, because I'm very concerned about the optimization. But when you say this, I should go for it :) - Thanks

Comment: @valipour: It's a pretty unusual requirement, so I'd be surprised if there were a ready-made tool to do it. But yes, go for it. Also consider *what* you're trying to optimize, and set yourself performance targets so you know when you can stop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a html page with images as base64 encoded strings in the src attribute you might consider using the [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) format instead. Most browsers supports the format and it embeds all external resources (including images).

```
var msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
msg.MimeFormatted = true;
msg.CreateMHTMLBody("http://www.google.com", CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressNone, "", "");
var stream = msg.GetStream();
var mhtml = stream.ReadText(stream.Size);
```

Comment: In Chrome, at least, Save As... mhtml doesn't actually embed the images as base64 data sources.  I can't believe there's not a simple app out there than can do this.  App, program, utility, whatever.  I'd even take an NPM package at this point.  All because we have a nice "web page", we need to get sent out as a newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression (regex) to extract URLs from img tags, translate them to absolute URLs using the Uri class, then use WebClient to download the target images. After that it's just a case of using Convert.ToBase64String to produce the Base64.