# How to get all images from a website and replace them with base64 encodings?

Tags: javascript, base64

How to get all images from a specific website and replace them with base64 encodings?
Server-side solutions would work.
like:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    //replace with base64 encoding
}
```

Why: I wanted to create an e-book (mobi) based on a RSS feed. I already converted the content to HTML but the images need to be local for display. Replacing the images base64 looked like the best solution.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? What prevents you from simply doing it ? And why would you do that ? To inline resources ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why would you want that? Or do you think of a serverside (non-javascript!) solution?

Comment: Do you want to do it server side or client side ? It doesn't seem to make sense to do that client side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

jQuery + canvas:

```
$("img").load(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this),
        jCanvas = $("<canvas width='" + $this.width() + "' height='" + $this.height() + "'/>"),
        oCanvas = jCanvas[0];

    oCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    this.src = oCanvas.toDataURL();
});
```

But this will only work if the image is on the **same domain** as the script.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K5RY3/3/

Answer (score 1):

First—and I'm not sure that this specifically applies to your situation—remember that `data` URIs aren't [supported](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) by IE ≤ 7 and IE 8's support is shaky; and that there can be [many disadvantages](http://dataurl.net/#advantages) to using `data` URIs.

That said, there are two places to worry about: `<img>` tags and CSS files.

I found [this tool](http://dataurl.net/#cssoptimizer) that will replace all image references in a stylesheet with its `data` URI representation.

I didn't see anything to do the same for `<img>`s in a HTML page, but [it wouldn't be hard to build something that does what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651042/201952).

Alternatively—and considering that base64-encoding all of your images will bloat filesize by 33%—you could use the [HTML5 app cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), which is designed for running HTML pages offline and [works](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps) in everything but IE ≤ 9.  (This is the approach I'd use.)

Just add a `manifest` attribute to the `<html>` element:

```
<html manifest="files.appcache">
    ...
</html>
```

*files.appcache* is a simple text file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
http://www.example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com/header.png
http://www.example.com/blah/blah
```

The [MDN article about app caches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Loading_documents) has much more in-depth information.